# How to binding Time-Dependent-Property of all the items in ObservableCollection<Class-with-a-Time-Dependent-Property> to a TextBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have lots kind of tasks (instances of TaskClass) stored in a ObservableCollection named TaskCollection. In class TaskClass, there was a TimeLeft property which changed dynamically when the task is running.

```
class TaskClass:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    TimeSpan TimeLeft{get;set;}
}
```

When one or more tasks were running, user could add some new tasks to TaskCollection.When a task is running, the task's TimeLeft property changed (increase or decrease).

A TextBox was used in the UI to display the total time needed for all tasks. I've tried to use a multi-bind to both TaskCollection and TaskCollection.Count. The total time will display in the TextBox just after user add/remove tasks. But when the existed task running (the TimeLeft property changes), the TextBox cannot notify.

How to binding TimeLeft prop of all the tasks stored in ObservableCollection to a TextBox, so that the total time left could display in time?

Comment: IMO your ViewModel should include somekind of `TotalTime` property that reflects the sum of the `TimeLeft` of the tasks. The viewmodel then needs to listen on the `PropertyChanged`-Event on all task-objects and update the `TotalTime` property if any `TimeLeft` property changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But when the existed task running (the `TimeLeft` property changes), the `TextBox` cannot notify.

This is because there is no notification for any of the data-bound properties when an individual `TimeLeft` property is set.

What you should do is to add a property to the view model that returns the sum of all `TimeSpan`s. You would then implement the logic to set this property in the view model where it belongs. Something like this:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Tasks.CollectionChanged += OnTasksCollectionChanged;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<TaskClass> Tasks { get; } = 
        new ObservableCollection<TaskClass>();

    public TimeSpan TotalTimeLeft => new TimeSpan(Tasks.Sum(x => x.TimeLeft.Ticks));

    private void OnTasksCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewItems != null)
            foreach (object task in e.NewItems)
                (task as INotifyPropertyChanged).PropertyChanged
                    += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(OnTaskPropertyChanged);

        if (e.OldItems != null)
            foreach (object task in e.OldItems)
                (task as INotifyPropertyChanged).PropertyChanged
                    -= new PropertyChangedEventHandler(OnTaskPropertyChanged);

        NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(TotalTimeLeft));
    }

    private void OnTaskPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) =>
        NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(TotalTimeLeft));

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "") =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Comment: That's what I want.